# How to iterate a variable in Java

Tags: java

So Im sort of stumped on how to do the following.

I have my program outputting the correct variables in a table like format that I want.  However, I dont quite understand how to make one of the variables increase in value as well.

Below is the code.

```
package annualsalarywithcommisions;

/**
 *
 * @author TDavis
 */
public class Calculations {

    public double baseSalary = 55000;
    public double localTotalSalary;
    public double salesTarget = 165000;
    public double potentialSalary;

    public void PayCalculator() {
        //Method for calculating the total wages paid to a sales rep.
        double localSales = ComissionsWk3.Sales;
        if (localSales < (.75 * salesTarget)) {
            localTotalSalary = baseSalary;
            //When sales are less than 75% of sales target, they only make
            //the salary.
        } else if ((localSales > (.75 * salesTarget)) && (localSales <= salesTarget)) {
            localTotalSalary = (.14 * localSales) + baseSalary;
            //Total salary is calculated with the 14% commission rate when
            //75% of the salesTarget has been met.
        } else if (localSales < salesTarget) {
            localTotalSalary = (.216 * localSales) + baseSalary;
            //Total salary is calculated with the acceleration factor and the 
            //base salary included when total sales exceeds the sales target.
        }
    }

    public double getCalculatedSalary() {
        return localTotalSalary; //method for returnin te' calculated salary total.
    }

    public double CompensationTable() {
        double localSales = ComissionsWk3.Sales;
        for (double counter = localSales; counter < localSales * 1.5;
                counter += 5000) {
            if (counter < (.75 * salesTarget)) {
                potentialSalary = baseSalary;
            //When sales are less than 75% of sales target, they only make
                //the salary.
            } else if ((localSales > (.75 * salesTarget)) && (localSales <= salesTarget)) {
                potentialSalary = (.14 * localSales) + baseSalary;
            //Total salary is calculated with the 14% commission rate when
                //75% of the salesTarget has been met.
            } else if (localSales < salesTarget) {
                potentialSalary = (.216 * localSales) + baseSalary;
            //Total salary is calculated with the acceleration factor and the 
                //base salary included when total sales exceeds the sales target.
            }
            System.out.println("Total Sales: " + counter + "\tTotal " + "Compensation: " + potentialSalary);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What I'm stumped on is how to make the output `potentialSalary` come back with the calculated `potentialSalary`.

Essentially whenever the 5k increase happens, get the 14% or 21.6% increase added into that variables total each time it runs through the loop and set it as such.

Any ideas are very much welcomed.

I have actually figured it out - but apparently cant answer my own question.  Below is the fixed code.

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package annualsalarywithcommisions;

/**
 *
 * @author TDavis
 */
public class Calculations {

```
public double baseSalary = 55000;
public double localTotalSalary;
public double salesTarget = 165000;
public double potentialSalary;

public void PayCalculator() {
    //Method for calculating the total wages paid to a sales rep.
    double localSales = ComissionsWk3.Sales;
    if (localSales < (.75 * salesTarget)) {
        localTotalSalary = baseSalary;
        //When sales are less than 75% of sales target, they only make
        //the salary.
    } else if ((localSales > (.75 * salesTarget)) && (localSales <= salesTarget)) {
        localTotalSalary = (.14 * localSales) + baseSalary;
        //Total salary is calculated with the 14% commission rate when
        //75% of the salesTarget has been met.
    } else if (localSales < salesTarget) {
        localTotalSalary = (.216 * localSales) + baseSalary;
        //Total salary is calculated with the acceleration factor and the 
        //base salary included when total sales exceeds the sales target.
    }
}

public double getCalculatedSalary() {
    return localTotalSalary; //method for returnin te' calculated salary total.
}

public double CompensationTable() {
    double localSales = ComissionsWk3.Sales;
    for (double counter = localSales; counter < localSales * 1.5;
            counter += 5000)

    {
        if (counter < (.75 * salesTarget)) {
            potentialSalary = baseSalary;
        //When sales are less than 75% of sales target, they only make
            //the salary.
        } else if ((counter > (.75 * salesTarget)) && (counter <= salesTarget)) {
            potentialSalary = (.14 * counter) + baseSalary;
        //Total salary is calculated with the 14% commission rate when
            //75% of the salesTarget has been met.
        } else if (counter < salesTarget) {
            potentialSalary = (.216 * counter) + baseSalary;
        //Total salary is calculated with the acceleration factor and the 
            //base salary included when total sales exceeds the sales target.
        }
        System.out.println("Total Sales: " + counter + "\tTotal " + "Compensation: " + potentialSalary);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Your title of the question says 'iterate a variable' can you please elaborate what do you mean by that? also your question is not very clear can you please add some more elaboration to it. and why are you returning 0 in method `CompansationTable()`?

Comment: To be clear, on each iteration of the for loop you want to System.out.println("Total Sales:".   And on that iteration you want the total to have been updated on the above calcs.  If the potentialSalary doesn't change you want to skip the print?

Comment: too much code, strange terminology and unclear question. If you can shorten the code and describe the problem more precise the answer may fall on your feet immediatelly :) and you should really not use uppercase methods and variables.

Answer (score 0):

The third case in your if/else will never be entered because of the previous case's <=. There's not really an upper bound on potential salary so it's hard to answer, but they have the potential to make base + 21.6% it looks like. So I'd make a function that took the sales and then provided the base + 21.6% of that. The `CompensationTable()` and `PayCalculator()` functions are confusing (should not be capitalized either). It looks like you were trying to make `CompensationCalculator()` into your potential function, but returned 0 instead of a value.